# Proof that the momentum operator is Hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, operators

I am trying to prove that the momentum $p_x$ operator is Hermitian, my approach is the following

$$<p_x>~=~\int \Psi^*(\vec{r},t)[-ih\frac{\partial}{\partial x}]\Psi(\vec{r},t)\, d^3r.$$

I try to do integration by parts but I cannot resolve the differential, as the integration is in respect to $\vec{r}$ and the partial is in respect to $x$.

Comment: $d^3r=dxdydz$ and you can integrate by parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just working with $\hat p_{x}$, you really only care about the integral over x, rather than the entire volume ($d^{3}r=dxdydz$). Anyways, a Hermitian operator is one such that $A^{\dagger}=A$. This means that $\hat p^{\dagger}=(\hat p^{*})'=\hat p$ where the prime indicates a transpose. A transpose in this case really means that the operator acts to the left. Assuming the wavefunctions vanish on the integration boundary, you should be able to show that 
\begin{equation}\int dx \,\Psi^{*}(x,t)(\hat p_{x} \Psi(x,t))=\int dx \, (\Psi^{*}(x,t)\hat p_{x}^{\dagger})\Psi(x,t)\end{equation}
Which means that the momentum operator is Hermitian. It may be instructive to work this out in 3D where $\hat p=-i\hbar \vec \nabla$ and the integral runs over the whole 3D volume.

Comment: But proving Hermitian over $x$ doesn't mean that it is Hermitian over the volume?

Comment: The operator in question is only dependent on x, so if it's Hermitian on x, it's Hermitian. The same procedure applies to the whole volume, even though to prove $p_{x}$ is Hermitian you don't need the whole volume integral.